# Validating request in node.js and quiting if error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, when a user is requesting resources from my server I of course wish to validate that the request itself is 'secure' and valid. Currently in my code I use this homebrew solution which looks something like:

```
if(assertThat(validator.isAlphanumeric,data.currentQuestion,next)){return;}
```

where `assertThat()` is

```
var assertThat = function(func,value,next){
    if(!func(value)){
        var err = new Error("[...]");
        err.status = 422;
        next(err);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but that `if` statement there to prevent further execution has irritated me quite a bit (as properly indenting it uses too much space, yet writing it on one line looks ugly). Is there a way within the Express framework to design a function that will work without that `if` statement somehow? I might be asking for the impossible, but as my experience with node.js is limited and I am trying to design this application as beautifully as possible I am checking none the less.

Comment: Have you tried throwing the Error in `assertThat` instead of calling `next`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the only way you could bypass the `if` is if you insert a custom middleware function before whatever route handler or middleware you were previously using `assertThat()` in. The middleware could for example take in a list of validators that you want to apply to the request. Example:

```
function validate(validators) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body;
    for (var i = 0, validators.length, v; i < len; ++i) {
      v = validators[i];
      if (!v.fn(data[v.name])) {
        var err = new Error('[...]');
        err.status = 422;
        return next(err);
      }
    }
    next();
  };
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
app.get('/foo',
        validate([
          { fn: validator.isAlphanumeric, name: 'currentQuestion' }
        ]),
        function(req, res) {
  res.send('Passed validation!');
});
```

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this way in which those middlewares function. Had no idea you could chain them like that in a single `app.get` call... will have to read through those docs better after all.